# When unit test fail, show the related file changes from git repo

Tags: node.js, git, unit-tests

Is there something that makes it possible to view the relevant file changes along with the unit tests that failed?

So, like after a failed test notification

```
× Test: Server startup test. Fail ×
   Error
       at C:\~\tests\integration\gentest.js:85:26
       at C:\~\server_init_app.js:51:6
       at _fulfilled (C:\~\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\q\q.js:797:54)
```

it will show the relevant (most recent) changes to the file that caused the test to fail

```
------------------------------ server_init_app.js ------------------------------
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..313371f
@@ -0,0 +1,24 @@
                 .use(nib())
                 .import('nib')
+                .import('nib/gradients');
```

I'm doing dev in node.js using mocha for testing.

I'm looking for either a software, tool, app that does this or a way to achieve this by combining whatever several tools it takes. I'm on Windows but open to linux solution, preferably that could work through cygwin.